# aws s3 sdk returns "You have attempted to create more buckets than allowed"

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using aws s3 SDK in my code. In my tests I'm trying to create/drop buckets for the test.

My sdk version is 1.11.800 :

```
<aws-s3-sdk.version>1.11.800</aws-s3-sdk.version>
<aws-java-sdk-core.version>1.11.800</aws-java-sdk-core.version>
```

The creation's code is exactly the same as in aws examples :

```
 public void createBucket(String bucketName){
        try {
            if (!s3Client.doesBucketExistV2(bucketName)) {
                // Because the CreateBucketRequest object doesn't specify a region, the
                // bucket is created in the region specified in the client.
                s3Client.createBucket(new CreateBucketRequest(bucketName));

                // Verify that the bucket was created by retrieving it and checking its location.
                String bucketLocation = s3Client.getBucketLocation(new GetBucketLocationRequest(bucketName));
                System.out.println("Bucket location: " + bucketLocation);
            }
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process
            // it and returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The exception :

```
22:32:33.949 [main] DEBUG com.amazonaws.request - Received error response: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: You have attempted to create more buckets than allowed (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: TooManyBuckets; Request ID: 4FE57EE4ACC6C7E4; S3 Extended Request ID: qIzyYNg6Il9J+ehR+JM3W5+RZWg43GJIU9v4EA5ajHG05bUydw8lN3qLZY5u/QjdXhV8tJlINMk=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: qIzyYNg6Il9J+ehR+JM3W5+RZWg43GJIU9v4EA5ajHG05bUydw8lN3qLZY5u/QjdXhV8tJlINMk=
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: You have attempted to create more buckets than allowed (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: TooManyBuckets; Request ID: 4FE57EE4ACC6C7E4; S3 Extended Request ID: qIzyYNg6Il9J+ehR+JM3W5+RZWg43GJIU9v4EA5ajHG05bUydw8lN3qLZY5u/QjdXhV8tJlINMk=; Proxy: null), S3 Extended Request ID: qIzyYNg6Il9J+ehR+JM3W5+RZWg43GJIU9v4EA5ajHG05bUydw8lN3qLZY5u/QjdXhV8tJlINMk=
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1811)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1395)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1371)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1145)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:802)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:744)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:686)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:550)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:530)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5062)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5008)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.createBucket(AmazonS3Client.java:1097)
```

- I got more than 100 buckets in my account but when I try to create a
  bucket in the aws console I create it successfully without any
  problems.
- When I create the bucket manually and run my other tests (that don't
  create this bucket) I can successfully put and delete content from
  the bucket so it isn't a credentials issue.

Comment: Have you raised an increase request before as AWS only allows you to create up to 100 buckets in your account?

Comment: What does `aws service-quotas list-service-quotas --service-code s3` print ?

Comment: {
    "Quotas": []
}

Comment: @NiteshSharma I already have more than 100 buckets and I can keep creating them via the console. I cant create more via the SDK.

Comment: Perhaps AWS has a hard limit on the number of buckets created with code.  Code can create dozens or hundreds of buckets at a time.  You can only create one bucket at a time with the console.  Reading @Gagan Bhat's answer, I suspect this is the case.

Comment: Take your app and the Java SDK out of the picture. Using the same credentials, can you create a new bucket using the awscli?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By default, an AWS account is soft limited to 100 S3 buckets.

You need to submit a service limit increase request by [creating a new case through the support portal.](https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home?region=us-east-1#). Once they override the default soft limit on your account you may create up to 1000 S3 buckets.

Read more about bucket restrictions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)

Comment: I already have more than 100 buckets and I can keep creating them via the console. I cant create more via the SDK.

Comment: https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home?region=us-east-1#! is the new link